# Conditional formatting not working on subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a form in form view with a continuous subform in it.

I have a conditional statement in the conditional formatting for the control in question (which is a combo box) on that continuous subform. This conditional, when evaluates true, disables the combo control for that record:

```
[Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate]<getStartDate()
```

I have also tried this statement:

```
[Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate]<#12/01/2016#
```

Interestingly, this does not work in the main form... but if I open the subform by itself this formatting works just fine.

Anyone have an idea of what may cause this?  I really need this to work in the main form.

PS. I'm using Access 2013.  I am proficient in VBA or any other language if that helps.

Comment: I've been experimenting with other functions and it seems `[Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate]` doesn't evaluate in a subform but `[ctlDate]` does... Can anyone expalin this behavior?  They both evaluate if I open the subform by itself... weird...

Comment: Try using `Debug.Print` and see what values it is evaluating.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.  Debug.Print does not work with the conditional format window.  However, I have tested for primitive type (>0, Is Null, Is Not Null, Len()>0, ##) which should then turn the box red. Same behavior, evaluates to a date or int type if I open the subform directly, but not when the subform is in the main form.

Comment: Put this code in one of the procedures on the form. `Debug.Print [Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate] & " : " & getStartDate()` Then open the `Immediate Window` to see the values.

Comment: Invalid Syntax, I don't think the Conditional Format window can access the immediate window in the VBA IDE.

Comment: No it can't. You will need to put that code into one of the procedures for a control on the form, i.e MouseMove or Click. You should then see the results in the immediate window. Once you establish that the results are as expected. i.e. two date properly formatted dates you can work on formatting the conditional formatting operations/syntax

Comment: You may be on to something here.  The `[Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate]` syntax throws and error.  Simply putting `ctlDate` evalutes. It also looks like `[frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate]` evaluates as well.  Is this just a weird idiosyncrasy or is there some deeper logic i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [DateDiff](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f) function and see if that works.

```
If DateDiff("d",[Forms]![frmCommuteInSub]![ctlDate],getStartDate()) > 1 then
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, please see the comment I just added to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have 2 options, it just depends on which suits you and your project.

1. Complete the conditional format based on a main form / subform relationship using the expression builder.
2. Complete the conditional format based using single value evaluation. However, in order to do this you will need to make sure the value you are evaluating is part of the table or more likely query you have the form b

Whichever route you choose, make sure to ensure that the variables or controls you are evaluating are producing correctly formatted results. That's half the battle!

More info:

http://www.iaccessworld.com/conditional-formatting-for-subform-or-datasheet-form/
https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/868555-demo-conditional-format-subform-unlimited-colours